# Why am I getting a KeyError: 'title' with feedparser?

Tags: python-3.x, feedparser

I'm using Python 3.6 and trying to get familiar with the feedparser lib. Now, when I'm using this code:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml')
d['feed']['title']
```

available at the official documentation site (https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html), I'm getting the before mentioned Key Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myName/PycharmProjects/NLTK/21.11.2018.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(d['feed']['title'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 356, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'title'
```